# I am trying set culture as Chinese Traditional language. but it's doesn't work it always set default culture

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have used CultureInfo for set Culture.
my code like below in C#:

```
 CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("zh-CHT");
```

Comment: How do you use the `culture` variable?

Comment: He is not set culture variable that's why not working maybe @KlausGütter

Comment: Do you mean that the variable `culture` is `null` after the assignment? What I wanted to ask is how you use the variable and what exactly is not working: do you use it as `IFormatProvider` parameter e.g. to string.Format? Or do you set `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and/ or `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`?

Comment: @KlausGütter I  have used that culture forget messages from a resource file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you please use the below code it's work fine for you I think

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("zh-CHT");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture.Name);
```

If it does not work then you can use like below code

```
private void SetCulture(HttpRequestMessage request, string lang)
{
    request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Clear();
    request.Headers.AcceptLanguage.Add(new StringWithQualityHeaderValue(lang));
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the first example works for me.